# C# Regex find line that are not commented

Tags: c#, regex, comments

I'm using `((?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/))|(--[^@].*[\r\n])` Regex to identify all the comments in the file. (I'm reading a PL/SQL file and it uses -- for single comments and /* */ for multiline comments)
This works fine and I'm able to get all the comments without any issues.

I want to get the code that are not matching to above regex.
So I used Regex `[^(((?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/))|(--[^@].*[\r\n]))]`

```
 MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, "[^(((?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/))|(--[^@].*[\r\n])])");
 for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Groups[0].Value);
 }
```

Then when I try to run it says

```
The file could not be read:
parsing "[^((?:/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*/]))*\*+/))|(--[^@].*[
])]" - Too many )'s.
```

How can I obtain the line that are not comments?

Comment: `[^...]` is a character class. It won't recognize the content as anything other than character class or character inside.

Comment: @nhahtdh If so there any other way that I can match the non comment code?

Comment: I hope your SQL doesn't contain `SELECT 'some -- string' FROM [some--table]` ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski PLSQL file having more than just sql queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the comments and get the uncommented text as follows

```
public static readonly string BLOCK_COMMENTS = @"/\*(.*?)\*/";
public static readonly string LINE_COMMENTS  = @"--[^@](.*?)\r?\n";
public static readonly string STRINGS        = @"""((\\[^\n]|[^""\n])*)""";

string sWithoutComments = Regex.Replace(textWithComments.Replace("'", "\""), ServerConstant.BLOCK_COMMENTS + "|" + ServerConstant.LINE_COMMENTS + "|" + ServerConstant.STRINGS,
                me =>
                {
                    if (me.Value.StartsWith("/*") || me.Value.StartsWith("--"))
                        return me.Value.StartsWith("--") ? Environment.NewLine : "";
                    return me.Value;
                },
                RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 1):

try it use another way:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, "((?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/))|(--[^@].*[\r\n])");
string result=text;
 for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
 {
     result=result.Replace(matches[i].Value);
 }
```